# Adding an expression in htmlOptions of CGridView

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I'm trying to set the htmlOptions using a value from the array used as DataProvider of the CGridView component (it's a CArrayDataProvider). In it there is a flag that will be either 0 or 1 (0 for font-weight: normal and 1 for bold)

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'$data["flag"] == 1 ? font-weight: bold; : font-weight: normal;'),
```

It didn't work, so I tried to set the style directly in the DataProvider (returning font-weight: bold; or font-weight: normal;):

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'$data["style"]'),
```

But the output is:

```
<td style="$data["style]">Value</td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `$data` or $row in `htmlOptions`. You have to extend the `CDataColumn`.

Refer to [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/314/cgridview-use-special-variable-data-in-the-htmloptions-of-a-column-i-e-evaluate-htmloptions-attribute/) for information on how to do it.

Comment: This helped me a lot, but what if I wanted to set some fixed style plus some dinamic. I tried to concatenete some string but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Yii v1.1.13 now has this functionality built into CGridView: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#rowHtmlOptionsExpression-detail

You can use $data for the model and $row for the row number to evaluate an htmlOptions array from a string. Since the syntax is a little weird I'll show an example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(       
        'columns' => array(     
            array(
               'name'=>'Column Name 1',
               "value"=>'$data->colVal',
            ),                      
               'name'=>'Column Name 2',
               "value"=>'$data->colExpression()',
            ),
            "modelAttributeUsingNameLabel",
        ),
     "rowHtmlOptionsExpression"=>'array(
                          "onclick"=>
                             "window.location = \'.$this->url.\'"
                  )')
 );
```

Notice that the php array for the htmlOptions is in a string. That is strange, but it is how it works!

Comment: very useful and easy to use

Answer (score 1):

htmlOptions has no access to $data.
So you can try this

```
'value' => '($data["flag"] == 1 ? "<b>$data->your_value</b> ":"$data->your_value")',
```